# Uncaught Error: Cannot find module './recipes' in React Native

Tags: react-native, import

So I'm trying to import files from the ./recipes folder but it keeps showing in the error that it can't find the module './recipes'

This is my App.js:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

import Home from "./Screens/Home";
import { Ampalaya, AdobongSitaw } from "./recipes";



<NavigationContainer>
        <StatusBar style="auto" />
        <Stack.Navigator>
          <Stack.Screen
            name="Home"
            component={Home}
            options={{ headerShown: false }}
          />

          <Stack.Screen
            name="Ampalaya"
            component={Ampalaya}
            options={{
              headerRight: (props) => <Logo {...props} />,
              headerTitle: "Back",
            }}
          />

          <Stack.Screen
            name="AdobongSitaw"
            component={AdobongSitaw}
            options={{
              headerRight: (props) => <Logo {...props} />,
              headerTitle: "Back",
            }}
          />
</Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
```

Also all those files are existing on their perspective folder. Still can't find a solution. Here is my folder structure:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nhnhA.png)

Comment: looks fine, please share screenshot of your folder structure hierarchy

Comment: Done, but it's only a link for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to import it as you are importing your Home Screen.

```
import Ampalaya from "./recipes/Ampalaya";
import AdobongSitaw from "./recipes/AdobongSitaw";
```

The only way you could achieve the way you are importing is to make a recipe module.

**Create index.js in your recipes folder.**

**import all your components into the file.**

**export the module with all components.**

```
//index.js
import Ampalaya from "./Ampalaya";
import AdobongSitaw from "./AdobongSitaw";

export { Ampalaya, AdobongSitaw };
```

Import the way you were doing it:

```
import { Ampalaya, AdobongSitaw } from "./recipes";
```

Comment: But I do have a 16 files inside the recipes folder and I do not want to have a lot of lines in my code.

Comment: Please check the edited answer. Try to follow the steps mentioned.

Comment: This shows... Cannot assign to read only property 'exports' of object '#<Object>' that error is from the index file inside the recipes folder.

Comment: module.export edited. please check

Comment: It's working now! Thanks a lot.

Comment: One last question, why do I have to create an index file there?

Comment: index.js act as an entry point to any folder. This is something I follow, you can rename it to any name you like. Then you have to access it like import { Ampalaya, AdobongSitaw } from "./recipes/yourFileName.js"